# Android emulator running on windows phone

Tags: android, android-emulator, windows-phone, emulation

I am thinking of making a final year project as the title mentions it should be an emulator for windows phone that runs android project. i have done some research and found nothing helpful
the following discussions also shows that it is not possible
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1841481

but as we have an emulator for windows why is it not possible to have one for windows phone.. 
just because windows phone is locked down???
and if it is possible then what kind of programming i am looking forward to? because i know there will be alot of system level programming in this project (IF IT IS POSSIBLE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would probably have to look into some way of rewriting the Dalvik VM to run on Windows Phone https://code.google.com/p/dalvik/

It is not impossible but it would take a serious amount of work. BlackBerry spent a lot of time working on their own version for PlayBook.

Comment: Thanks that gave me some hope :)

Comment: If that helped you could you give it a +1 or mark it as an answer please?

Comment: +1 yes it helped me i was looking for clue from where to start actually and it did

Comment: I meant click the tick that it is to the left of my answer :P

Comment: or even just the up arrow if you don't want to click the tick

Comment: i cant do that because it requires 15 reputation :P